# Select the outer edges?

Tags: python

How can I select just the outer edges? I have tried several things without success. I need to delete/dissolve the outer edges ,but this needs to be done with code.

[image: Outer Edges]

Comment: Can you clarify .. by outer edges =>  boundary edges eg all edges of a simple plane?

Comment: I thought I had this solved in a weird and long way ,but it fails sometimes. Yeah, I think I’m talking about boundary edges. You can see there’s 4 sets of lines which makes a continuous loop . I need to select just the outer ones.